# shell_exec gives wrong output from 'systemctl status php8.1-fpm'

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

On my Webpage i use the follow Codeblock:

```
<p>ufw:         <?=shell_exec("systemctl status ufw         | grep -w 'Active:' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print \$2, \$3}'");?></p>
<p>ssh:         <?=shell_exec("systemctl status ssh         | grep -w 'Active:' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print \$2, \$3}'");?></p>
<p>mysql:       <?=shell_exec("systemctl status mysql       | grep -w 'Active:' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print \$2, \$3}'");?></p>
<p>apache2:     <?=shell_exec("systemctl status apache2     | grep -w 'Active:' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print \$2, \$3}'");?></p>
<p>php8.1-fpm:  <?=shell_exec("systemctl status php8.1-fpm  | grep -w 'Active:' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print \$2, \$3}'");?></p>
<p>proftpd:     <?=shell_exec("systemctl status proftpd     | grep -w 'Active:' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print \$2, \$3}'");?></p>
```

The output shows:

```
ufw: active (exited)
ssh: active (running)
mysql: active (running)
apache2: active (running)
php8.1-fpm: active (running) sh -c grep -w
proftpd: active (running)
```

Why is the php line so different?

I was try different things for instance escape critical Signs but nothing was helpful.

Comment: As an aside to the output, not sure how to properly check some of the services on a page which is being run on those services. If php isn't running - how did the page run?

Comment: Whether the page is still displayed or not is not the problem. It's about the output of the command.

Comment: Ignoring PHP for a moment, when you run that command from the CLI does it do the same thing?

Comment: @ChrisHaas in the terminal it looks OK, only 'active (running)' appears there

Comment: Well, grep and awk are just dealing with the output of the first command, so echo that completely and inspect it. Maybe there’s multiple lines matching?

Comment: The solution is the additional parameter -m1 in grep. This ends the search for the first hit. thx @ChrisHaas